# value of variable not consistent at end of one loop and start of next loop

Tags: r

Please see the code below, where I remove certain columns from a data frame, and keep a track of the current column I am in, using a variable called, 'col'.

Problem
I reduce the value of 'col' if I delete a column from the data frame, however, that does not seem to show effect. On printing the log, I see that the value of col at the start of the loop does not seem to reflect the decrement of the variable 'col'

Data

```
col1 = c(1,2,3,4,NA)
col2 = c(2,3,NA,NA,NA)
col3 = c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA)
col4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
col5 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
col6 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1)
col7 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,2)
col8 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,8)
col9 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
col10= c(1,2,3,4,5)
df = data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10)
```

Code

```
col = 0
totalcolumns = ncol(df)
for (col in 1:totalcolumns)
{
 cat(paste("value of col at the start of the loop==",col,"\n",sep=""))

 if(length(which(is.na(df[,col]))) == nrow(df))
 {
    cat(paste("all nas at col==",col,"\n",sep=""))
    cat(paste("removing column",col,"\n",sep=""))

    df[,col] = NULL

    col = col - 1 
    totalcolumns = totalcolumns - 1

    cat(paste("totalcolumns ==",totalcolumns," col==",col, "\n",sep=""))
 }

 cat(paste("value of col at the end of the loop==",col,"\n\n",sep=""))
}
```

Output

```
value of col at the start of the loop==1
value of col at the end of the loop==1

value of col at the start of the loop==2
value of col at the end of the loop==2

value of col at the start of the loop==3
value of col at the end of the loop==3

value of col at the start of the loop==4
all nas at col==4
removing column4
totalcolumns ==9 col==3
value of col at the end of the loop==3

value of col at the start of the loop==5
value of col at the end of the loop==5

value of col at the start of the loop==6
value of col at the end of the loop==6

value of col at the start of the loop==7
value of col at the end of the loop==7

value of col at the start of the loop==8
all nas at col==8
removing column8
totalcolumns ==8 col==7
value of col at the end of the loop==7

value of col at the start of the loop==9
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , col) : undefined columns selected
```

Note that the value of 'col' at the end of the fourth iteration of the loop is 3, but at the start of the fifth iteration, it shows 5, where I was expecting it to show 4

EDIT:
As Buckminster and MrFlick say, reducing the value of 'col' inside the for loop, doesn't show any effect by R design. But is this a good thing? See difference between C and R below

R code

```
> for(i in 1:9){print(i);if(i==9){i=i-1}}
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
```

C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int i = 0;

 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
  printf("value of i==[%d]\n",i);

  if(i == 9)
  {
   i--;
  }
 } 

 return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Will never terminate
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
9
...
infinitely printing
9
..
```

Answer (score 1):

Any changes to the values of the variables you used as your iterators will be lost when the next iteration start. Since you've initiated your loop with

```
for (col in 1:totalcolumns)
```

It will run `totalcolumns` times and `col` will increase by one each time. Your attempt to change

```
col = col - 1
```

will be reset for the next iteration. This makes even more sense when you think about a case like

```
for(x in c("apple", "orange", "banana")) {
   x <- paste("i want your", x)
   print(x)
}
```

It doesn't make sense to think that changing `x` inside the loop will have any effect on how the iterations proceed.

Comment: thanks for the response. But is this a good design. See my edit above. If I'm manually decrementing the variable, shouldn't it show effect? Please see my edit above, where I compare with C code

Comment: If you want a loop that may never terminate, use a `while` loop. R `for` loops and C `for` loops are quite different. Whether or not it's a good design is kind of off topic. It is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your loop lies in this code: `for (col in 1:totalcolumns)`. At the start of each loop iteration, `col` will be assigned the next value in the vector `1:totalcolumns`, regardless of what happened in the previous iteration.

Comment: thanks buckminster. But is this a good design? See my edit above. Since I'm decrementing the variable manually, shouldn't it show effect? Please see my edit above, where I compare with C code